# Wordpress SQL query different results

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I added a custom Visual Composer element and want to output a result of a query. However when I output this query(1) it gives other results then when I output this query(2).

```
// declared vars
global $wpdb;
$nn = '{{ post_data:ID }}';
$nn1 = (string)$nn;

 1)   $results2 = $GLOBALS['wpdb']->get_results( "SELECT guid FROM wp_posts WHERE post_parent = 526 AND guid like '%pdf'", OBJECT );
 2)  $results2 = $GLOBALS['wpdb']->get_results( "SELECT guid FROM wp_posts WHERE post_parent = ".$nn1." AND guid like '%pdf'", OBJECT );
```

When I output the 526 string(query 1) it gives the right result however I want the output to be with the var because every post has its unique ID.

I've also tried to put the var in a string so it isn't being seen as a POST_ID

```
$nn = '{{ post_data:ID }}'; 
$nn1 = (string)$nn;
```

Any ideas to where this is failing?

What i've tried in the meantime:

```
$nn1 = (string)$nn;
$nn2 = strval($nn);
$nn3 = settype($nn, "string");

$results1 = $GLOBALS['wpdb']->get_results( "SELECT guid FROM wp_posts WHERE post_parent = ".$nn1." AND guid like '%pdf'", OBJECT );
$results2 = $GLOBALS['wpdb']->get_results( "SELECT guid FROM wp_posts WHERE post_parent = ".$nn2." AND guid like '%pdf'", OBJECT );
$results3 = $GLOBALS['wpdb']->get_results( "SELECT guid FROM wp_posts WHERE post_parent = ".$nn3." AND guid like '%pdf'", OBJECT );
$results4 = $GLOBALS['wpdb']->get_results( "SELECT guid FROM wp_posts WHERE post_parent = %d AND guid like '%pdf'", $nn3, OBJECT );
```

All of the above are returning an empty string which means there is still something wrong with the var

When I echo the whole string it returns the right mysql query:

```
echo ("SELECT guid FROM wp_posts WHERE post_parent = ".$nn."");
//output
SELECT guid FROM wp_posts WHERE post_parent = 526;
```

When I execute that query, it gives me the right solution:

```
$results6 = $GLOBALS['wpdb']->get_results( "SELECT guid FROM wp_posts WHERE post_parent = 526", OBJECT );
// output
[6]=>object(stdClass)#8030 (1) {
["guid"]=>
string(69) "http://blabla.pdf"}
```

Greetz

Comment: I meant to type = 526 (integer) - edited question

Comment: Your `$nn1` variable literally contains `{{ post_data:ID }}` and not a number.

Comment: how can I put the {{ post_data:ID }} into a number then?

Comment: WordPress has several methods to get post ID's. Or do you already have a php variable containing the id value? This looks like a templating language that needs to be rendered but that will not happen in mysql.

Comment: Well the $nn is the post ID but I need to have that value to put into the sql query, otherwise it wont give me the right results. Hence question on how to put it into a number. (this is the output of the $nn if I var dump it : string(18) "526")

Answer (score 0):

None of your tests seem to include the one query you've shown to be working:

```
$GLOBALS['wpdb']->get_results(
    "SELECT guid FROM wp_posts WHERE post_parent = $nn", 
    OBJECT 
);
```

There's no need to do any type conversions, especially not to string. `$nn` should contain `int 526`.

full disclosure: I'm not a WP dev and I have no idea how you got from `'{{ post_data:ID }}'` to `256`, also `string(18) "526"` seems like a very weird output to me. (groetjes aan de daddykaters!)

Comment: So when I activate the show errors for wpdb it gives me next error:    `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '{ post_data:ID }} AND guid like '%pdf'' at line 1.` I use the '{{ post_data:ID }}' to get the id of the post, it's how the visual composer plugin works. (When i dump the $nn it clearly dumps a string with a value that corresponds with the post ID.